# Do I need to check if document is ready when I implement js after the iframe I want to change

Tags: javascript, html

In a html file I have an iframe and some rows later I implement a js script from another file.

With the js I want to change the source of the iframe.

Do I have to use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function)` for that even though my script occurs later (than the iframe) in the code?

Comment: No. If the element exists at the time the script is run it does not require it assuming you only want to change properties of iframe element itself. If you want inside the iframe is different story

Comment: @Blauharley My iframe is empty before the script is loaded, so I guess there is no need to use this kind of event.

Comment: @charlietfl That's all I wanted to know. And I only want to change the property of the iframe itself. Thanks for your answer